# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for applications started from the desktop

Tags: environment-variables

I have Qt Creator installed on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.  When I launch Qt Creator from the desktop I can build the application I am working on but cannot run or debug it.  After struggling quite a bit I found that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set for applications that are run from the desktop.  If I start Qt Creator from bash (where LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set in .bashrc) everything runs and debugs perfectly.

How do I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that it is set for all running applications?

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a bug in the application itself. It should have a wrapper script that correctly sets any needed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables. Be careful when writing such a script, though, since you do not want to have any empty portion of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` string between the colons it uses as path separators. For example, this could result in a  bad path, if the variable was empty initially (resulting in a leading empty string before the colon):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/path/for/app"
```

So, when adding a path, you'll want to test for the empty string first. For example, using shell code:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}/some/path/for/app
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file /etc/ld.so.conf containing:

```
# Begin /etc/ld.so.conf
/lib
/usr/lib
/usr/X11R6/lib
# whatever else #
```

Update the dynamic loader cache by running:

```
ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `.bashrc`, also set the environment variable in `.profile`. This file will get processed and loaded by your session, so it should affect everything running as your user. Also: This file says it is not read by Bash if `.bashrc` exists, but it seems to apply still (perhaps since Bash inherits the X session from where it was started). It doesn't hurt to have the variable in both files, though.

Comment: I tried creating .profile as well with no luck.

Comment: I read somewhere that there is a "safety" feature of Ubuntu(Debian?) that can't let you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH at startup since it is overwritten after loading .profile. There are still workarounds.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/47958

Answer (score 0):

set it in /etc/bash.bashrc near the top to make a system wide change on bootup.